# What is request signature in citrus pay

Tags: android, citrus-pay

I am getting error as `{"pgRespCode":"111","redirectUrl":"","txMsg":"Invalid signature key"}`
Anyone know what this request signature and how to generate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 111 is error message for Invalid signature key. Check if you are using the right keys for right environment.(Production will work with production keys).

The merchant is required to generate a signature and send it along with the payment request.

You can check here on how to create signature - https://developers.citruspay.com/documentation/web-payments/citrus-hosted-checkout/generate-signature/